# Installing a vintage bathroom sink

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, bathroom-fixtures, renovation

I recently purchased this vintage sink that was mounted in a cabinet vanity. I am wondering if it is possible to wall mount this and if anyone has any ideas on what I may need. I was thinking about using floating shelf brackets and (hopefully) sliding them in the rear holes and also siliconing it to the wall. I wasn't sure if this was a wall mount sink originally or if it needs to be in a cabinet. Looks like it may have holes/slots for legs too. I have no idea what the brand of the sink is, either. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is how it was originally mounted.

Comment: Plan on front legs at least.  Silicone be just for sealing, it will never hold a ceramic sink.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options

1 Look for metal legs for example these (perhaps too ornate) ones
[image]

2 a pair of legs made custom for those large square holes near the front.

Either way add basin brackets with spacers at A plus adhesive at B.
[image]

You need front legs.  People will lean or even sit on it.

Comment: thank you! I will look for that stuff!

Comment: A lot of sinks were designed assuming the drain & P-trap could take a lot of the weight, but I agree that front legs (ones designed for strength, not show) are best practice.

Comment: 2 pieces of steel pipe for strength with decorative covers would work quite nicely if you can't find anything strong _and_ decorative.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft that's what I was wondering about the p-trap and drain supporting it at all. I got a heavy duty p-trap to help.

Comment: Actually maybe brackets with spacers is a bad idea.  "A" is not meant for brackets and without the wall backing it, brackets might break it.  Screw a big piece of wood on the wall that completely fills that gap, provides a facing for area A, and extends down a few inches.  Screw the brackets to that.